# Can I track how far a request makes it onto the internet?

Tags: macos, networking, ping

If I send a request over the internet is there a way for me to track all the servers it goes through?

I know I can in the terminal type:

```
ping superuser.com
```

and get:

```
PING superuser.com (198.252.206.16): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 198.252.206.16: icmp_seq=34 ttl=49 time=298.413 ms
```

is there a way to see all the servers it went through and track its path?

I am curious about this as sometimes my network goes down and I thought it would be interesting if I could ping and see how far it makes it before it fails.

I would be interested if there is a way to do this in the terminal or with a command line or gui tool etc

If this is not possible, is there a similar way to achieve this sort of task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `traceroute` instead of `ping`. It will show you all the hops or track a packet if you will. (max 30 hops) Or you could use [VisualRoute](http://www.visualroute.com/download.html)

To use trace route, just use it like you use ping.
 `traceroute superuser.com` (*nix systems) or `tracert superuser.com` (Windows)

Comment: on windows pathping is another awesome option

Comment: Please keep in mind that `traceroute` and other programs of the sort only provide a view of 1/2 of the route involved in a two-way communication channel... the route back can be and often is completely different.

Comment: And traceroute by default uses ICMP not TCP as protocol. So it might (and will) be possible that your pakets go completely different ways using traceroute compared to ie. calling the same server in your browser.